# MUI datepicker giving error on cancel button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-date-picker

I am facing issues on changing value of date in an MUI date picker:

> value.isBefore is not a function

My code:

```
   <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <MobileDatePicker
      className="text-[14px] !text-white"
      format="DD/MM/YYYY"
      defaultValue={dayjs('2023-01-19')}
      value={event.date}
      onChange={(v) => handleDateTime("date",dayjs(v?.$d).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))}
      inputFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
      sx={{
        fontSize: "0px",
        padding: "0px",
        "& .css-1t8l2tu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input":
          {
            padding: "0px!important",
            color: "white",
          },

        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
          border: "0px!important",
        },
      }}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
```

`handleDateTime` function

```
const handleDateTime = (key,v) =>{
    setEvent((prevEvent) => ({
      ...prevEvent,
      [key]: v,
    }));
  }
```

and in the `useState` hook

```
const [event, setEvent] = useState({
 title: null,
 type: null,
 date: null,
 start: null,
 end: null,
 start_time:null,
 end_time:null,

 });
```

[image]

Comment: [value.isBefore is not a function in AdapterDayjs](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/10715) Check this issue. Most probably the `value={event.date}` is not a dayjs date so the component is not able to parse it. Another possible issue i see is that you are passing `format` prop as well as `inputFormat`.

`format` prop is available in the newer v6 pickers and it was earlier used as `inputFormat` in v5. So please check the version you are on.